# WildFly 8.2.0 and Zabbix 3.0 and Remote JMX Monitoring

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jmx, zabbix

Good morning to everyone.
I've a problem while configuring Jboss wildfly 8.2.0 on linux for jmx remote monitoring for Zabbix 3.0, in domain configuration.
I'm using the profiles "full" and "full-ha".
These are the string I've enabled:

```
(profile=full-ha)
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
<expose-resolved-model/>
<expose-expression-model/>
<remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>

(Profile=full)
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
<expose-resolved-model/>
<expose-expression-model/>
<remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>
```

Inside the host.xml, I've insert the voice for every virtual server the configuration for the remote jmx monitoring, here one for example:

```
<servers>
        <server name="server-one" group="main-server-group">
            <!-- Remote JPDA debugging for a specific server-->
            <jvm name="default">
              <jvm-options>
                <!--<option value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"/>-->
<option value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"/>
<option value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10150"/>
<option value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"/>
<option value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"/>
<!--<option value="-Dcom.sun.logmanager.Logmanager"/>-->
<!--org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager-->
              </jvm-options>
           </jvm>
           <!--      -->
        </server>
```

For every server, I've entered a different port.

```
But when I try to start the domain, I receive the following error:
09:26:50,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-one.status] (ProcessController-threads - 3) JBAS012017: Starting process 'Server:server-one'
[Server:server-one] WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
[Server:server-one] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:61)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.server.DomainServerMain.main(DomainServerMain.java:86)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Server:server-one]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:460)
09:26:51,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-one.status] (reaper for Server:server-one) JBAS012010: Process 'Server:server-one' finished with an exit status of 1
[Host Controller] 09:26:51,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (ProcessControllerConnection-thread - 2) JBAS010926: Unregistering server server-one
```

So, I've tried putting this string into the domain.conf:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final.jar"
```

But in this case I' receive the following errors:

```
[Host Controller] 09:28:18,462 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS010922: Starting server server-one
09:28:18,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-one.status] (ProcessController-threads - 3) JBAS012017: Starting process 'Server:server-one'
[Server:server-one] Could not load Logmanager "/application/jboss/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final.jar"
[Server:server-one] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /application/jboss/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final.jar
[Server:server-one]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[Server:server-one]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[Server:server-one]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[Server:server-one]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[Server:server-one]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[Server:server-one]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[Server:server-one]     at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:191)
[Server:server-one]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[Server:server-one]     at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
[Server:server-one]     at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
[Server:server-one]     at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
[Server:server-one]     at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:823)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:260)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:456)
[Server:server-one] WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
[Server:server-one] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:61)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.server.DomainServerMain.main(DomainServerMain.java:86)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Server:server-one]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:460)
09:28:19,384 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-one.status] (reaper for Server:server-one) JBAS012010: Process 'Server:server-one' finished with an exit status of 1
```

So, what can I do? Why I receive these errors and how can I resolve and finally start my virtual server?

Thanks to everyone for your help

Greetings
Red

Comment: Just a generic comment. May not be related to the specific question. For several reasons, we don't use zabbix to monitor the jmx parameters directly from WildFly (or any other java based application). We use jolokia in-between. Jolokia converts JMX into http and zabbix read the http data. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just tackled this issue yesterday. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398948/jboss-log-manager-error) summarizes the solution, but the underlying issue is this:

- The command line must override the `java.util.logging.manager` to **org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager** with the directive `"java.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"` (the value is the class name, not the jar)
- This requires that the jbss logging jar be in the classpath at boot time, so the command line must insert the jar into the boot classpath with this directive: `"-Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final-redhat-1.jar"` (the actual version may vary depending on what EAP version you are running).
- In addition, you must add the jboss logging package to the boot time module list. The launcher script (conf modifier) has a line like this:

  if [ "x$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS" = "x" ]; then
     JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.byteman"
  fi

and it needs to be extended to include the jboss logging package:

```
if [ "x$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS" = "x" ]; then
   JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.byteman, org.jboss.logmanager"
fi
```

On that last part, you can skip the env variable since that gets converted to a command line set system property like this:

```
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS
```

which is to say, you could just set that system property directly.

The underlying cause that requires this tweaking is the JMX command line settings which activates the java.util.logging very early in the boot process, as can be observed in your log here:

```
[Server:server-one]     at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
[Server:server-one]     at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
[Server:server-one]     at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:823)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:260)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:456)
```

As such, removing the JMX command line options also fixes this issue, which you could compensate for by activating JMX services later in the boot process, so you have options.

Comment: Hi, I've tried settings the optons that you shared, but now, even with the -Xbootclasspath, loading the logmanager module, I receive the following error:
          Error: Could not find or load main class org.jboss.logmanager

And then exit from the shell. I've copied the path jar from the command line, so I'm sure it's correct.

Comment: Can you paste in the error log lines ? Also, we found, and I thought this was our weird setup, but it might be affecting you as well, the file configuration/logging.properties is **generated** on jboss startup, but in this case, util.logging will be initialized before this file is generated so it might be missing or contain invalid settings (we had a non-existent directory for the server.log).

Comment: .... and the failure caused by an invalid logging.properties file actually bubbles up to a **ClassNotFound** error which is very misleading, but the error stack trace makes it clear what's going on.

Comment: Hi, when i start the domain.sh, it doesn't even start, it just print the options line, the error of "could not find..." and then exit.
The only log that I find are host-controller and process-controller

Comment: That last one report the following line:
2016-04-14 14:36:36,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-two.status] (reaper for Server:server-two) JBAS012010: Process 'Server:server-two' finished with an exit status of 130
2016-04-14 14:36:36,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (reaper for Host Controller) JBAS012010: Process 'Host Controller' finished with an exit status of 130

Comment: Your xbootclasspath does have a "/p" on the end, right ?

Comment: This is my Xbootclasspath:
 -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final.jar"